# Отображение картинок на локальном сервере Django

Tags: python, html, django

Как сделать так, чтобы на localhost отображались изображения, которые я вставил в HTML?
P.S. Но при этом, если просто открыть страницу через браузер (не на локальном сервере), то всё показывается исправно.

Перепробовал несколько вариантов, например `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`, но что-то не выходит. Так как это сделать?

Comment: Что у вас не выходит? Важно понимать, что вы уже пробовали. Тем более вы могли ошибиться в реализации, потому я горячо рекомендую вам подробнее описать состояние сервера и представить код (а лучше - [минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), чтобы мы могли помочь вам! Вам также стоит изучить, как [задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Это очень важно сделать, если вы хотите успешно пользоваться сайтами Stack Exchange в будущем

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from . import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Попробуй этот вариант

Comment: Не-а, просто ничего не происходит, кстати, несмотря на то, что HTML и картинка в одной папке, ругается, что не находит файл
Not Found: /home/W4KJ6Jhzaqyr4I11ir97QT0n9WDarCqGMnHgw-HkUQ4.jpg
Может в этом проблема?

Comment: Было бы лучше, если бы вы подробнее описали решение, это может сильно помочь автору. В целом советую почитать, [как написать хороший ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).
Это важно сделать, если вы хотите успешно пользоваться сайтами Stack Exchange в будущем

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте внести изменения в файл setting.py. Пример:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```